# Initialize ng-model string with function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

Is there a way to conditionally initialize ng-model to a certain string with a function? In the following, ng-bind works, but ng-model doesn't:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.value = "hello";
  $scope.value2 = "hello2";
  $scope.get = function (bool) {
      return (bool) ? "value" : "value2";
  };
}]);

<html ng-app="app">
  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ng-bind="{{get(true)}}"></div>
    <input ng-model="{{get(true)}}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**Clarifying Edit:**
I have two separate data sets that a given input could effect. Which one it effects is conditional on values elsewhere in the model. There are dozens of different input types, and I want to avoid writing ng-switch's into every single one, as that would get rather messy.

**Example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/fKlbN8qcjGjzqjRayviT?p=preview

Comment: How do you expect to **set** that `ng-model`? Initialize it in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cleanest and easiest way to conditionally set the value of your model.

`<input ng-model="yourModel" />` then in controller:

`$scope.yourModel = (condition) ? 'hello1' : 'hello2';`

**EDIT for clarified question**

Ok, I came up with something using `ng-init`. Apparently you cannot use a function with `ng-model`. I had yet to try that so I was surprised it did not work.

I ditched the custom directive as it was not needed.

Your HTML will be something like this:

```
<div ng-init="input1 = getBinding(setB,2)">
  <input ng-model="input1" /> <!-- shows bbb -->
</div>
<div ng-init="input2 = getBinding(setA,0)">
  <input ng-model="input2" /> <!-- shows a -->
</div>
<div ng-init="input3 = getBinding(setA,2)">
  <input ng-model="input3" /> <!-- shows aaa -->
</div>
```

Your controller:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.setA = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa'];
  $scope.setB = ['b', 'bb', 'bbb'];

  $scope.getBinding = function(set, index)
  {
    return set[index];
  }
}]);
```

So moving forward, rather than setting the name like `input1 = ...`, `input2 = ...` etc, if you're going to use a repeater, you can use the $index value to create the model name like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="setItem in setA" ng-init="setA$index = getBinding(setA, $index)">
  <input ng-model="setA$index" /> <!-- shows 3 inputs of values a, aa, aaa -->
</div>

<div ng-repeat="setItem in setB" ng-init="setB$index = getBinding(setB, $index)">
  <input ng-model="setB$index" /> <!-- shows 3 inputs of values b, bb, bbb-->
</div>
```

DEMO - http://plnkr.co/edit/70QG3s3ovppkXcUqOmPj?p=preview

Hopefully with this you can come up with your solution.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question then. Can you create a simplified jsfiddle or the example not working?

Comment: Sure thing. I'll do that as soon as possible and add it as an edit. My apologies for being unclear.

Comment: I added a plunker for you to look at.

Comment: It's brilliant. Definitely the most clear of all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for whatever reason you "need" to do this in the view, you could use the init to set a variable to the return of your get function, and set the model to that value

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="whatever.value" ng-init="whatever = get(true)" />
    {{var1}}
    {{whatever}}
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.var1 = { value: "hello" };
    $scope.var2 = { value: "hello2" };
    $scope.get = function (bool) {
        return (bool) ? $scope.var1 : $scope.var2;
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dPn3A/

Otherwise, just do it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngInit like this:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="titel=get(true)">
    <div ng-bind="titel"></div>
    <input ng-model="titel" />
  </body>
```